# How to solve when parsing CSV file return empty values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I am using ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.7. I have written ruby back-end script that will create one CSV file on every 15 min interval using cron job.

Back-end ruby script:

```
 CSV.open("count.csv", 'wb',:col_sep=>',') do |csv|
 # header row
   csv << ['id', 'count']
   models = Model.all
   models.each do |obj|
      csv << [ obj.id, obj.get_count]
   end
 end
```

From above script CSV file(count.csv) created successfully. In Rails app,

```
 CSV.foreach("count.csv", :quote_char => '"', :col_sep =>',', :row_sep =>:auto, :headers => true) do |row|
   count =  row["count"].to_i if row["id"].to_i == @id
 end
```

I need to parse count value from that CSV file. but problem is when the time of cron execution, I unable to get count value from that CSV file return zero for all record and after execution finish I can get value of count. But I need count value always whether the cron execution stop or start, Can any one help me to resolve or any suggestion ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Are you sure `@id` is initialized?

Comment: @daniel - Yes i have initialized. The problem occur during the time of ruby script execution. In Rails reporting side I got zero value for all data. I don't how its happen? any guess?

Comment: Why are you doing all this as opposed to simply calling `obj.get_count` in Rails?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on `count.csv`? How about the location? Can you open and read it using `File.open`?

Comment: Take it the csv back-end script is taking awhile to write the output to the file - would it help to move the models loop outside of the CSV.open function - parse a big string - then write it out to the CSV file in one go. Means the file is opened by the CSV writer for a shorter time.

Comment: @mu - I seen an error in heroku logs console like rake aborted!
Permission denied - /app/public/count.csv. How to resolve?

Comment: You'll have to store the CSV somewhere other than the filesystem on Heroku. You dynos won't necessarily have access to the same file system or even have access to a writeable file system.

Comment: @mu - please explain me. under rails /public folder we have all rights(Write,read,execute)?

Comment: Not on Heroku you don't. Why bother with a CSV at all? Why not just add an extra table to your database?

Answer (score 1):

```
models = Model.all
models.each do |obj|
  csv_string << [ obj.id, obj.get_count]
end

CSV.open("count.csv", 'wb',:col_sep=>',') do |csv|
# header row
 csv << ['id', 'count']
 csv << csv_string
end
```